# Progress bar bootstrap interaction not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I'm really new to html and i am trying to run a progress bar. It's idea is to load till 100% with an interval between the percentages. In order to test it i simply made it to interact with my back button, so when you click on "Back" it should load, but sadly it doesn't work.

```
$('#pay').click(function() {

  var timerId, percent;

  // reset progress bar
  percent = 0;
  $('#pay').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#load').css('width', '0px');
  $('#load').addClass('progress-bar-striped active');


  timerId = setInterval(function() {

    // increment progress bar
    percent += 5;
    $('#load').css('width', percent + '%');
    $('#load').html(percent + '%');



    if (percent >= 100) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      $('#pay').attr('disabled', false);
      $('#load').removeClass('progress-bar-striped active');
      $('#load').html('payment complete');



    }

  }, 200);


})
```

**and the html:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pBar.js"></script>
</head>



    <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="load" style="width:0%">
      0%
    </div>
  </div>



<button type="button" id="pay" class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off"  >Back</button>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work. I saw a similar topic here, but coudn't find the answer.

Comment: It works: https://www.codeply.com/go/adJHEcFEde ... check your browser console (F12) for errors.

Comment: I opened the link you gave and it doesn't run it. :(

Comment: It works for me. did you try F12 to see what the console says?. and why is this tagged bootstrap-4? your code has bootstrap 3.

Answer (score -1):

I've gone ahead and ran your code in `Codepen`, [here](https://codepen.io/pen/bMKWLX), and it's functioning.
Please use CTRL+Shift+J to check the console for any errors being thrown, perhaps a browser extension being the issue.

Comment: No errors are shown when i open it.. And i only have AdBlocker as an extension.

Comment: Have you tried running this in another browser? Don't know why my post was downvoted considering it's completely functional when tested cross-platform...